# Unlimited connected surface with $K>0$

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature

It is known that every compact surface has an ellyptic point. But is there a smooth surface (embedded in $\mathbb R^3$) which has positive Gaussian curvature and is not contained in a ball?

The hyperboloid has points with negative curvature, and all points of the paraboloid have curvature $0$ (correct?). So I can't find a suitable example...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "the hyperboloid": In Euclidean $3$-space there are hyperboloids of two qualitative types, and it's not clear you've considered both. ;)

Comment: You are right, I had forgotten the two-sheets hyperboloid! So is its curvature everywhere positive?

Comment: Yes it is. But what happens to the Gaussian curvature as you go towards infinity on the two sheeted hyperboloid? What about asking the same question, but with the modification  that there is a positive constant, such that the curvature is always greater than that constant?